# Preventing the dd command on extra drives

Tags: hard-drive, dd

I use `dd` a lot day to day for writing Raspberry Pi SD card images.

However every now and then I slip and by accident `dd` the wrong partition and thus  killing my other drives.

I was wondering if there was a way to be able to block writing using `dd` to say `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc`.

Comment: Close voters: Ubuntu runs on the Raspberry Pi as of RasPi 2. Ryanteck: We assume you are using a Pi 2 with real Ubuntu. If not then you're better of asking on [unix.se] if the answer below does not work for you.

Comment: also you could be writing images *for* raspberry Pi on an ubuntu machine

Comment: mchid is right, I run full ubuntu on my Laptop & Desktops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Linux, so it's easy. Type `echo $PATH` and find a directory that 1) you have write access to; and 2) it is earlier in the list than the directory you get from `type -p dd`. Put this file in that directory, called `dd`, and make it executable via `chmod +x`.

Here is the file:

```
----------------------------- cut here ---------------------------
#!/bin/bash
# try to prevent foot-shooting via dd - complain if if= or of= is mounted
debugmode=1
#
# either abort with a message or pass everything to the real dd
realdd="/usr/bin/dd"
if [ $debugmode = 1 ] ; then
    realdd="/bin/echo"
fi
if [ ! -x "$realdd" ] ; then
    echo "$0 cannot find the real dd at $realdd" >&2
    exit 255
fi

errors=0

function diskok () {
    # passed a parameter, if=... or of=... 
    # if the argument to if= or of= is "WRONG", pull the plug
    param=$1;
    device="${param##?f=}"

# replace this with checks of your choice. I'm simply excluding any word in /etc/fstab 

    if [[ $( grep -q "$device" /etc/fstab;echo $? ) = 0 ]]; then
    echo "Trying to dd a mounted device $param" >&2
    (( errors++ ))
    fi
}

laundry=""

# Re: Those tests for if and of. You can just do if [[ $1 = if=* ]] and if [[ $1 = of=* ]]. Or, better yet, use a case statement. –  muru 7 mins ago
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]] ; do
    case "$1" in
    if=*)
            diskok "$1" ;;
    of=*)
            diskok "$1" ;;
    esac
    laundry="$laundry $1"
    shift
done
if [ 0 -eq $errors ] ; then
    eval "$realdd $laundry"
else
    echo "Saved"
fi
----------------------------- cut here ---------------------------
```

When you have tested it sufficiently, change `debugmode=1` to `debugmode=0`.

Here are my tests:

```
w3@aardvark:~(254)$ df
Filesystem        1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5         170416096  29962928 131773488  19% /
none                      4         0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                1938252        12   1938240   1% /dev
tmpfs                390632      1104    389528   1% /run
none                   5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                1953148       444   1952704   1% /run/shm
none                 102400        24    102376   1% /run/user
/dev/sda6         302248384 247234972  39637036  87% /home
/home/w3/.Private 302248384 247234972  39637036  87% /home/w3
/dev/sdb            3840544   1229408   2611136  33% /home/w3/mnt/CLIPZIP
w3@aardvark:~(0)$ dd bs=8293 if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sda5 of=/home
Trying to dd a mounted device if=/dev/sda
Trying to dd a mounted device of=/dev/sda5
Trying to dd a mounted device of=/home
Saved
w3@aardvark:~(254)$ dd bs=8293 if=/dev/sdaa of=/dev/sdaa5 of=/homae
bs=8293 if=/dev/sdaa of=/dev/sdaa5 of=/homae
```

Remember to change the test to the test you want.

Thanks to @muru for [[ and case

Comment: Re: Those tests for `if` and `of`. You can just do `if [[ $1 = if=* ]]` and `if [[ $1 = of=* ]]`. Or, better yet, use a `case` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you could write a wrapper script to prevent yourself from making misatkes, but having such a false sense of security established, you're going to have risky behaviour on other systems because you're used to a level of comfort that only exists in your system.

Therefore my answer is:

Think before root and no, there is no way to ***block*** other devices. When the block device is accessible to root, then `dd` can also access it. `dd` does only what you tell it to do.

### `dd` is also known as **D**isk **D**estroyer **;-)**

Comment: WRONG! `dd` is `$(type -p dd)` = `/bin/dd`. My `$PATH` is `/home/w3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:...` which means that any of `/home/w3/bin/dd`, `/usr/local/sbin/dd`, `/usr/local/bin/dd`,`/usr/sbin/dd`,`/usr/bin/dd`, and `/sbin/dd`, IF THEY EXISTED, would be executed instead of `/bin/dd`.

Comment: @waltinator Why is your PATH so weird?

Comment: Also, +1 for best practices.

Comment: My PATH contains directories containing programs I might want to run. I got tired of having to type the whole path to them. What is weird about it?